# How do I check if a nested JSON property exists and how many nested properties it has?

Tags: javascript, json

This quandary of mine is mainly based on the number of levels of complexity. I'm trying to figure out the JavaScript logic, but the JSON syntax gets complicated too, so any suggestions are appreciated.

I have a JSON file with more or less the following structure, except I have a whole lot more properties of each code type:

```
[{
  "000": {
    "code": "A",
    "description": "Poor circulation",
  },
  "001": {
    "code": "B",
    "description": "Pain in foot",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Right":"1",
        "Left":"2"
      }
    }
  },
  "003": {
    "code": "C",
    "description": "Exostosis",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Ankle":"1",
        "Foot":"2",
        "Leg":"3",
        "Thigh":"4"
      }
    }
  },
}]
```

The majority of the codes are like code A, and they're to be left alone. However, I need to filter and mark all codes that are like B (that is, having a "subcodes" property AND just the two nested properties "Right" and "Left") to have a '+' next to them; and codes like C (with any subcodes but just "Right" and "Left") to be marked with a '*'.

Assuming I set a variable for the JSON file, how can I filter these? The rest of my code pushes all the descriptions into an array and the codes into an array to feed them into a div, but how can I have an array alongside with just the codes that have subcodes, and then further filter them according to their child values?

Basically, my end goal is to have a div with all the codes like this:

```
A    Poor circulation
B  + Pain in foot
C  * Exostosis
```

Should I abandon the array method altogether? Is there a simpler way? I'm using just vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: It would help people to help you, if you show us your code.

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/mmckegg/json-query to filter

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate the object's values and check the conditions.

```js
function getValues(data) {
    return data.reduce(
        (r, o) => r.concat(
            Object
                .values(o)
                .map(({ code, description, subCodes }) => [
                    code,
                    subCodes ? 'Left' in subCodes[0] && 'Right' in subCodes[0] ? '+' : '*' : ' ',
                    description
                ].join(' '))),
        []
    );
}

var data = [{ "000": { code: "A", description: "Poor circulation" }, "001": { code: "B", description: "Pain in foot", subCodes: { "0": { Right: "1", Left: "2" } } }, "003": { code: "C", description: "Exostosis", subCodes: { "0": { Ankle: "1", Foot: "2", Leg: "3", Thigh: "4" } } } }];

console.log(getValues(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty `reduce` hack that fits you end goal of having a div like this

```
A    Poor circulation
B  + Pain in foot
C  * Exostosis
```

```js
const data = {
  "000": {
    "code": "A",
    "description": "Poor circulation",
  },
  "001": {
    "code": "B",
    "description": "Pain in foot",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Right": "1",
        "Left": "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "003": {
    "code": "C",
    "description": "Exostosis",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Ankle": "1",
        "Foot": "2",
        "Leg": "3",
        "Thigh": "4"
      }
    }
  },
};

let divElement = "<div>\n";

const reduceToDiv = (acc, curr) => {
  if (data[curr]["code"]) {
    const description = data[curr]["description"];
    if (data[curr]["subCodes"]) {
      const subCodes = data[curr]["subCodes"][0];
      if ("Left" in subCodes && "Right" in subCodes) acc.push("B  + " + description);
      else acc.push("C  * " + description);
    } else acc.push("A    " + description);
  }
  return acc;
};

divElement += Object.keys(data).reduce(reduceToDiv, []).join("\n") + "\n</div>";
console.log(divElement);
```

Comment: This worked really well; however, some codes have "left," "right", and other values, which should be marked with a * instead of a +. Is there a way to make the code check if there is ONLY "right" and "left" and nothing else?

Comment: This will do the trick then `const obj = data[curr]["subCodes"][0]; return Object.keys(obj).length === 2 && obj["left"] && obj["right"];`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial input is an array with one element, I don't know if you did it on purpose but this works with your given array:

```js
const input = [{
  "000": {
    "code": "A",
    "description": "Poor circulation",
  },
  "001": {
    "code": "B",
    "description": "Pain in foot",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Right":"1",
        "Left":"2"
      }
    }
  },
  "003": {
    "code": "C",
    "description": "Exostosis",
    "subCodes": {
      "0": {
        "Ankle":"1",
        "Foot":"2",
        "Leg":"3",
        "Thigh":"4"
      }
    }
  },
}];

const filterJson = arr => {
return Object.values(arr[0]).map(el => !el.hasOwnProperty('subCodes') ? `A   ${el.description}` : JSON.stringify(el.subCodes).includes('Right') && JSON.stringify(el.subCodes).includes('Left') ? `B  +${el.description}` : `C  *${el.description}`);
}

console.log(filterJson(input));
```